# VB.Net Changing the value in a different text boxes with 1 function based on name

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, textbox

Ok. I have done this in Php with a function before. I just don't know how to do it in VB.

I have a character sheet creator for a game I am making. What I am wanting to do is write a single function, where in you click on a button and it will pass the text box name (so that it knows which text box to edit), as well as the value inside of the text box (to make sure that the new character stat ceiling is taken into account).

In my mind, the psuedo code behind the button would look something like

```
Private Sub Button_Click
     AddtoValue(Textbox1,stats)
End Sub

Public Sub AddtoValue (NoIdea,NoIdea2)
     dim ObjectName as Object, ObjectText as string, Textasnum as integer

     Objectname = frmmain.noidea
     ObjectText = objectname.text

     textasnum = convert.toint32(objecttext)
     objecttext = textasnum

     [If Statements to check value of objectname for rules validation, and then noidea2 to figure out which point pool to take from and change if passes rules validation]
End Sub
```

Essentially, I need to know what to put for noidea, and noidea2, like, byval or byref or what?

Comment: Does your button know the textbox object on the form or just the textbox name?

Comment: that's what the sub inside the button is for. The first argument passed would be the name of the textbox (i.e. TextBox1 being the name of the textbox), and the second value would be a second textbox named Stats

Comment: Ok, is the button on the same form as the textboxes? If so, it makes it very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Create a procedure something like this:

```
Private Sub ProcedureName(ByVal NameOFTextBox as String, _
                          ByVal ValueToAssign as String)
     Dim xTextBox as TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls(NameOfTextBox), TextBox)
     xTextBox.Text = ValueToAssign
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
ProcedureName("txtBoxName", "NewValue")
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Private Sub ProcedureName(ByVal CtrlName As String, ByVal NewVal As String)
    Dim xCtrl() As Control = Controls.Find(CtrlName, True)
    For Each iControl As Control In xCtrl
        If iControl.Name = CtrlName Then
            Dim xTxt As TextBox = DirectCast(iControl, TextBox)
            xTxt.Text = NewVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not quite correct. Me.Controls will only search the top-level controls on the form. If a control is embedded in a panel, tab, or other container, this code will not find the textbox. Instead, you need to use `Me.Controls.Find` function with the `SearchAllChildren` parameter set to true.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net, it is very much possible to send objects to function calls using reference.

Hence, your sub signature will look something like this:

```
Public Sub AddtoValue (Byref textboxObj as TextBox, Byval stat as String)

    textboxObj.text = stat

End Sub
```

Comment: The only time that you want to send an object byref is if you actually need to change the object itself, NOT any properties within the object. In your example, you would allow the method to change the textboxobj, i.e. `textboxobj = New TextBox()`, which is most likely not what is desired. The one non-obvious exception is strings: since assigning a string a new value creates a new instance of the string, if you change a string parameter, it should be passed as byref.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarified comments, you should be able to pass and access the textboxes directly.

Here is what your AddToValue method should look like:

```
Public Sub AddtoValue (theTextBox As TextBox, theStatsBox As TextBox)
     dim Textasnum as integer

     If IsNumeric(theTextBox.Text) Then
         textasnum = convert.toint32(theTextBox.Text)
     Else
         textasnum = 0
     End If

     [If Statements to check value of objectname for rules validation, 
      and then noidea2 to figure out which point pool to take from and 
      change if passes rules validation]
End Sub
```